# How to change a variable without making a new one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to change a variable without making a new one in python?

here is an example:

```
x = True


def reverseX():
  x = not x


print(x)
reverseX()
print(x)
```

now this will return an error because it thinks that I was making a new x in the reverseX thing
is there a way for me to use the x that's at the top of the script in the reverseX thing?

btw, I know that I can use the return or just not use the reverseX thing, but sometimes you just need to use a def
also, I know that I can pass the x variable through the call but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you could do it by making `x` a global variable:

```
global x
x = True

def reverseX():
    global x
    x = not x

print(x)
reverseX()
print(x)
```

While this does work, I do not recommend it. As using global variables in more complex projects can lead to some problems, explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). A much better way of doing it would be:

```
x = True

def reverseBool(var):
    return not var

print(x)
x = reverseBool(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've been searching for this for too long

Comment: And probably also explain [why `global` is basically always bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439743/why-shouldnt-i-use-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: @tripleee I edited the answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Yup, much better.

Comment: I really don't understand why you need the `global x` at the start of the script? When I remove it nothing happen. And when I keep it Pycharm gives me this warning: `Redeclared 'x' defined above without usage`